# How to create a JWKs key from a CRT encoded in PEM format

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, jwk

I have a CRT file:

Example:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
MIIDijCCAvOgAwIBAgIJAKRvtQxONVZoMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMIGLMQswCQYD   
aXJlbGVzcyBOZXR3b3JrczEMMAoGA1UECxMDVEFDMSMwIQYDVQQDExpteXNlcnZl 
ci5hcnViYW5ldHdvcmtzLmNvbTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEA 
zRwqc9prVXycGhHcsAjGPzC2MKU4DhXSr86Z89Jk8/cXEJBJ0C/NgdAqqDgxneUh 
nVyxGxODa7BNGAWSagdCsKLrbkchr479E3xLfgdc3UzAJITLGCXGiQ66NwQDyM5I 
YWxpZm9ybmlhMRIwEAYDVQQHEwlTdW5ueXZhbGUxIDAeBgNVBAoTF0FydWJhIFdp 
cmVsZXNzIE5ldHdvcmtzMQwwCgYDVQQLEwNUQUMxIzAhBgNVBAMTGm15c2VydmVy 
LmFydWJhbmV0d29ya3MuY29tggkApG+1DE41VmgwDAYDVR0TBAUwAwEB/zANBgkq 
hkiG9w0BAQQFAAOBgQBp71WeF6dKvqUSO1JFsVhBeUesbEgx9+tx6eP328uL0oSC 
fQ6EaiXZVbrQt+PMqG0F80+4wxVXug9EW5Ob9M/opaCGI+cgtpLCwSf6CjsmAcUc 
b6EjG/l4HW2BztYJfx15pk51M49TYS7okDKWYRT10y65xcyQdfUKvfDC1k5P9Q== 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I know that this CRT is encoded in PEM. But i want to create a JWK key from this file how should i go about doing this ?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am also in need of a solution similar to you using javascript. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084352/pem-to-jwk-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to convert your PEM to JWK.

```
const jwk = require('jwk');
const myKeyJWK = jwk.readCertificate('crykey-my-key');
```

Comment: What language is this?